# Looping through Api

Tags: reactjs

```js
function renderUsers() {
    for (let i = 0; i < setdata.length; i++) {
        player = setdata[i].Player;
        Channelname = setdata[i].ChannelName;
        port = setdata[i].Port;
        ip = setdata[i].IP;
        console.log("hello friend", setdata);
        console.log("Inside ForLoop", setdata[i].Player);
        console.log(setdata[i].ChannelName);
        console.log(setdata[i].Port);
        console.log(setdata[i].IP);

    } getPostData(player, Channelname, port, ip);
}


function getPostData(players, Channelnames, ports, ips) {
    console.log("insideFunction Row1", players, Channelnames, ports, ips);
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
        data: {
            PlayerName: players,
            ChannelName: Channelnames,
            Port: ports,
            IpAddress: ips
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        auth: {
            username: 'admin',
            password: 'password'
        }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
        Postdata([response.data]);
        Postdata.push([response.data]);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

In GUI  Table it not stay in  1 numbers it's show 2 number(flicker) when I use ForLoop I want 1 number each table row to display in it

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-forest-tclge?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The codesandbox is not working.

Comment: you need to learn more about `useEffect` , `useState` of react hook. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: can you give me some example?